# Jenkins Builds - Worklight Ant Task failing - Neither application nor shell descriptors exist

Tags: shell, ant, jenkins, ibm-mobilefirst

My jenkins builds have been failing and after analysing we see that the worklight ant scripts have some issues below is the error seen, Can anyone please check the error and let us know what could be the possible reasons.

Worklight Ant Task version 6.1.0.01.20140922-2007

buildAndDeployAnt.xml:138: Failed initializing BuildConfiguration: Neither application nor shell descriptors exist

below is the ant xml snap shot for line 138

[image]

Thanks
dj

Comment: Hi DJ.
It looks like it doesn't find your application folder.
Can you please check that the echo message that you have before the build:
_"building application from ... "_ actually prints the correct application folder.
Thanks.

Comment: Hi Issahar, thanks for your response, but i have checked the application folder and it does exist.  buildAppCenterApplication:
     [echo] building application from IBMAppCenter/apps/AppCenter , this does contain android, common, iPhone and build-settings.xml files and folders.

Comment: build-settings.xm is unrelated to this process; does the application-descriptor.xml exist?

Comment: hi Idan, Thanks for your response, Applicationdescriptor does exists in the apps directory folder.

Comment: From the Jenkins source, "shell descriptor" is a Jenkins artifact, it could be that the problem is at the Jenkins side. https://svn.jenkins-ci.org/tags/hudson-1_162/hudson/main/core/src/main/java/hudson/tasks/BuildStep.java

Comment: Hi Idan, I have checked the outputFolder directory and the AppCenter-iPhone-6.1.wlapp file is not getting generated in case of failed builds, Can you please suggest  and help. However in succesful builds the AppCenter-iPhone-6.1.wlapp file is getting generated.

Comment: Well, at this point you're supposed to provide the error that you get when the build fails...

Comment: Hi Idan the error is same as in my questions buildAndDeployAnt.xml:138: Failed initializing BuildConfiguration: Neither application nor shell descriptors exist, Is this something to do with the comapatibily issue of iOS 8 with App center ? in Worklight 6.1.0.01.20140922-2007

Comment: The "Shell Descriptor" in question I think refers to a MobileFirst shell-descriptor.xml file: https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/documentation/getting-started-6-3/advanced-topics/shell-development-concepts/. Are you working with a Shell/Inner project or just a regular MobileFirst application?

Comment: Hi Andrew, This is not MobileFirst Application, it is just worklight version 6.1.,

Comment: The shell-descriptor.xml Andrew mentioned also exists in 6.1, but I guess that doesn't matter otherwise you would've recognized it.

Comment: @djrecker, you might as well upgrade to the latest Studio and Ant scripts by upgrading to the latest 6.1.0.2 iFix - you're version is quite old.

Comment: Hi.
The error comes from the build when it doesn't find the shell-descriptor.xml, after it looked for the application-descriptor.xml.
Can you check that "mobileApplicationSource" points to the application folder and inside it you have application-descriptor.xml?

Comment: I will close this question as the root cause was due to changes in App center code,

Comment: @djrecker, thanks but you cannot close questions - you can either supply an Answer below or Delete the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error "Neither application nor shell descriptors exist" is seen in cases where IBM App center files are either deleted by mistake in your repository. Please check file changes related to IBM App center.